# Consider the set $\;A=\left\{3-\dfrac{4}{x}:x\ge2\right\}$. How do I prove that $1$ is the minimum?

Tags: real-analysis, discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, proof-explanation, supremum-and-infimum

Consider the set $\;A=\left\{3-\dfrac{4}{x}:x\ge2\right\}$.

I want to prove that Set A has a minimum or doesn't.

$x \ge 2$

$\dfrac1{x} \le \dfrac1{2}$

$\dfrac4{x} \le \dfrac4{2}$

$-\dfrac4{x}\ge-2$

$3-\dfrac4{x}\ge1$

Thus, I have found that any element in A is always bigger or equal to 1. Thus, I know that 1 is a lower bound. But is that enough to prove that it is the minimum of A since it 1 is in the set A. if it is enough, why? I then tried to prove by contradiction that 1 is the minimum, but I went nowhere. I said :
Assume that there is $b>0$ such that $1<b<3-\dfrac4{x}$ for all $x
\ge 2$.
Can someone please show me how to show 1 is the minimum by contradiction? it should be possible since it's true that 1 is the minimum.

Comment: "Thus, I have found that any element in A is always bigger or equal to 1. Thus, I know that 1 is a lower bound. But is that enough to prove that it is the minimum of A since it 1 is in the set A."  **Yes**, it certainly is enough.  You have proven that $~1 \in A~$ and that for any $~r \in A, ~r \geq 1.~$  By definition, this signifies that $1$ is the minimum element in $~A.$

Comment: There is no need for a proof by contradiction. Let $f(x)=3-\frac4x.$ you just proved that $\forall x\ge2\quad f(x)\ge f(2).$ So $f(2)$ is the smallest element of $A,$ that's all ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We first have to prove that $1$ belongs to $A$, and then that it's the smallest element in $A$.

To prove $1\in A$ it's sufficient to notice that for $x = 2$ we indeed get $1$.

To prove $x = 1$ is the minimum by contradiction, we assume that $\exists s \in A$ such that $s < 1$.
Then we substitute, getting

$$3 - \dfrac{4}{x} = s$$

$$\dfrac{4}{x} = 3-s$$

Now since $s < 1$ it holds that $3-s > 2$, therefore $\dfrac{4}{x} > 2$

But the set $A$ is defined for those $x$ that are greater or equal than $2$, and hence $\frac{4}{x} > 2$ implies $x < 2$ which is a contradiction.